# Defining several variables simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, list, function, indexing

For each object in my Python list, I want to define an integer which is the first index of the object:

```
firstindex( some object ) = mylist.index( some object)
```

How do I make such a definition for all objects simultaneously?

I tried doing this:

```
firstindex = []
i=1

while i < 100 :
    firstindex.append( mylist.index("i") )
    i=i+1
```

But it tells me that 'i' is not in the list. However the list is of the form [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,....]

Comment: Remove the quotations around `i`

Comment: This error isn't related to "defining several variables simultaneously". See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to the following:

```
firstindex = []
i= 1

while i < 100 :
    firstindex.append( mylist.index(str(i)) )
    i=i+1
```

Your previous code searched for an item in the list with the value "i" which is the string "i". You instead want to search for the value of the variable i which is the string "1" then "2" then "3" and so on. So you should simply search for the index of str(i).

`Str(i)` returns a string of the value in i.

Comment: So it consists of strings. How can I change the data type of each list element?

Comment: @fredflintstone2000 I edited my answer. Please edit your question so that others would not misunderstand it.

Comment: Thank you. What if I wanted to avoid creating the list firstindex and instead have a bunch of variables firstindex_1, firstindex_2, ... How would I implement that? @RoaaGharra

Comment: @fredflintstone2000 Why would you want to define 100 variables instead of using 1 list?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a dictionnary?

```
d = dict() # or d = {}
for i in range(100):
   d['firstindex_'+str(i)] = ""
```

This would create a dictionnary of size 100 with all values as empty strings. You can access it with d['firstindex_0'] through d['firstindex_99'].

Answer (score 0):

That's because the funct list.index(obj) return the index of the object in the list.

```
>>> ["foo", "bar", "baz"].index("bar")
1
```

And your list  `"mylist"` is a list of object that may not content the index `"i"`, that is a String